# PAM standard macros and logging on CentOS7

Tags: c, linux, centos, centos7, pam

According to the `D(x)` macro defined in `pam_macros.h` (**[source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/pam/pam-9/pam/libpam/include/pam/_pam_macros.h)**) and used as follows:

```
D(("Hello PAM World"));
```

Where is this log located on `CentOS7`?

Note that I am using as flag `debug` in my `pam.d` conf file.

I tried also the following command:

```
grep -rnw '/var/log/' -e "Hello Pam World"
```

But with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file you link, there are these lines at the top:

```
/*
 * This is for debugging purposes ONLY. DO NOT use on live systems !!!
 * You have been warned :-) - CG
 *
 * to get automated debugging to the log file, it must be created manually.
 * _PAM_LOGFILE must exist, mode 666
 */

#ifndef _PAM_LOGFILE
#define _PAM_LOGFILE "/tmp/pam-debug.log"
#endif
```

So it looks like the output will be directed to `/tmp/pam-debug.log`, but you have to create it before, and give it full read-write permissions:

```
$ touch /tmp/pam-debug.log
$ chmod 666 /tmp/pam-debug.log
```

Looking to the Linux version of this file, it looks like it is written to `/var/run/pam-debug.log`, but only if it is compiled with `PAM_DEBUG`.

There a nice comment in `configure.ac`:

```
if test x"$enable_debug" = x"yes" ; then
       AC_DEFINE([PAM_DEBUG],,
                [lots of stuff gets written to /var/run/pam-debug.log])
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this solution but it still doesn't work. Take into account that the code above is the open provided by Apple, probably (surely) the version on CentOS has a different setup.

Comment: @vdenotaris: You are right, it is slightly different. I've just checked the Linux version and the file is `/var/run/pam-debug.log`. Also, PAM must be compiled with macro `PAM_DEBUG`, not `DEBUG`, as the Apple one.